# Java Servlet and Lucene search: cannot forward after response has been committed

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, lucene

I know this error has been discussed several times and I have read most of them, but my problem still remains. I don't know what to do!

I want to do an index search in lucene index and return the results in a jsp file.
It works for one result, but when I use a `for` loop to get all the results, it gives the error (cannot forward after response has been committed).

Here is my servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String queryfield = request.getParameter("query");
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    FSDirectory index = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("F:\\temp\\index.lucene"));
    int hitsPerPage = 10;
    String[] fields = new String[]{"Title","Body"};
    MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fields, analyzer);
    parser.setDefaultOperator(Operator.AND);
    Query q;
    try {
        q = parser.parse(queryfield);

        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        TopDocs docs = searcher.search(q, hitsPerPage);
        ScoreDoc[] hits = docs.scoreDocs;

        ArrayList<result> t = new ArrayList<result>();
        for(int i=0;i<hits.length;++i){
            int docId = hits[i].doc;
            Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
            result r = new result();
            r.title = d.get("Title");
            r.url = d.get("URL");
            r.body = d.get("Body");
            t.add(r);
            request.setAttribute("Results",t);
        getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);

        }
        return;

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What am I missing?!

Comment: do you have session check in your jsp page?

Comment: @BirhanNega No, I don't. Should I ?

Comment: Put `getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);` out of the `for` cycle (i.e. right before the `return` command`).

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Thanks. I don't get errors anymore. But I have trouble displaying my arraylist in jsp! For that I think I should ask a new question!